# How to transfer files form folders and sub-folders to specific folders created by file name pattern in C# (File2specific Folders)

Tags: c#

As you can see in code, folders are created during move file button. my question is that how to moves files in that particular folders, I have tens of millions of files and want to moves in that particulars. I am new in c#.

[image]

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace File2Folders
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        List<string> fileName = null;
        List<string> fileNames = null;
        private void btn_browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Clear();
                    fileName = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath).ToList();
                    fileNames = fileName.Select(item => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item).Substring(1, 4)).OrderBy(n=>n).ToList();
                    listBox1.DataSource = fileName.Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)).ToList();
                    listBox2.DataSource = fileNames;         
                }
            }
        }
        private void btn_move_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    fileNames.ForEach(item => Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(fbd.SelectedPath, item)));
                
                }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=net-6.0 check this one out

Comment: Please try to avoid using words like *crore* that are not globally understood and use for example *million* instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this fuction that I use sometimes.

```
    bool FileCopyPasteRename(string source, string destination, string renameTo)
    {
        bool res = false;
        string renameDestination = Path.Combine(destination, renameTo.ToLower());
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(source))
            {
                File.Copy(source, renameDestination, true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //cath error ex.Message
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Once its a bool function, you can check if returns true and the delete source file.

Answer (score 0):

To move a file you can use **method Move** in File. It takes as parameter the path of the file you want to move and the destination **including and the file name**
here is an example

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\HP\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\fileToMove.txt";
string destination = @"C:\Users\HP\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Dummy\fileToMove.txt";

try
{
    File.Move(filePath, destination);

}
catch (Exception e)
{

    Console.WriteLine("We coudnt move the file becouse of: " + e.Message);
}
```

For more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=net-6.0

Comment: Thank you sir for response, I am browsing source and destination path, now what can I use to move files, in your cade you have fixed the destination path .

Comment: Do you have a method that selects the file you want to move, so you can extract the path from there? And also the same for the destination. I supposed that you could get those info